# A bad profile in Stack Overflow can affect the future working and recruiting process for the person who created such account?

Tags: discussion, jobs, profile-page

Let me explain my question. Let's say a person makes a profile on Stack Overflow and for negligence and/or laziness that person doesn't read and ignore all the rules of the site, start posting duplicate questions, trolling and rude questions and comments which of course are downvoted and deleted.

The person gets banned for asking questions and later deletes his account.
The same person wants to get a job at a big software company, is it possible that his bad actions with this site in the past may affect him in the future? Even if he deleted the account? And if he did not delete the account still may affect him in a way that he doesn't get the job?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357044/i-was-recently-asked-for-my-stack-overflow-reputation-score-in-a-job-interview

Comment: It depends. If you share with HR that you have or had an account on Stack Overflow you might get questions about it. How you answer those questions is none of our business.

Comment: And what if that person doesn't want to lie and HR asked why he deleted his account? There are overprotectors of this site and if you say that you were trolling with it can make them angry

Comment: @ElMacho: I don't see what business it is why you deleted an account that has nothing to do with your work. They can ask, but you don't have to answer. Just like they can ask if you have a Facebook account, but you don't have to answer. Indeed, I would personally be concerned about an HR department that started to inquire so heavily about your personal behavior.

Comment: It is very likely you won't ever get a job because of that time you asked a fake question on SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it *possible*? Yes.

If one used their own name or a well-known pseudonym on SO, then it is at least theoretically *possible* for their deleted account to be deanonymized. This would primarily be through the discovery of a comment that mentioned the user name and thus unambiguously links that username to an anonymized user ID number. With such a number, one can find all of the posts for that user.

Is it *likely*? I rather doubt it.

I don't think most employers care about SO actions enough to undertake the kind of painstaking forensic analysis needed to unearth a deleted account. This is especially unlikely if they don't actually know that you *have* such a deleted account to unearth. After all, doing this requires sifting through comments, and those are not exactly easy to search through. Deleted users don't have a profile, so it's not like they can go and find this person's comments.

For accounts that aren't deleted, which are in some way linked to that particular person, yes, it's possible for employer's to use SO behavior in their hiring decisions. Just as it is possible for an employer to use any online behavior they can easily identify with you as part of their hiring decisions.

Comment: And what are the odds that an employer uses SO behavior in their hiring decisions?

Comment: Probably somewhere in the range of `x:y`

Comment: @KevinB not funny, people like you are the reason why there is evil in the world. I thought sarcasm and bad treatment was not allowed in here... but hey! you are the boss, you got the points, we get nothing. whatever!

Comment: @ElMacho: I thought your comment was a joke myself. How could you expect *anyone* to know what the odds of that are? Are there surveys out there of hiring practices and SO behavior, that could reduce things down to a number? Your comment is a question that cannot reasonably be answered with any kind of authority.